# iOS multitasking : let a stream play when the app is in the tray

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, multitasking

Does anyone knows how I can let an audio stream play (from a webview ou in a AVPlayer component) after the app lose focus (when the home button is pushed) ? In iOS 4.2. I know I must read about multitasking but if you could just point out a few things for that particular case, that would be great. Exactly the same behavior as if you click a stream link and it's open in Safari. You have to shutdown the application in the multitask tray to end it.

Like if you want to listen to a radio station while working in another app.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the documentation on background processes on iOS, specifically the requirements for playing background audio: 
[iOS Background Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW14)

The associated audio programming guide will probably guide you through any specifics needed to properly implement your audio stream: [Audio Session Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875)